# Find command gets error in .sh but not in terminal

Tags: bash

I have a script thats gets an error in a find command:

```
echo "find ${logPath} -mtime +${cutOffDays} -type f -name ${dateInNameLogs}.log -depth 1 -print -delete 2>&1" >>$logFile
rslt=$(find ${logPath} -mtime +${cutOffDays} -type f -name ${dateInNameLogs}.log -depth 1 -print -delete 2>&1)
```

The log file shows:

```
find /Users/craig/Desktop/logs -mtime +21 -type f -name *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][-_][0-9][0-9][-_][0-9][0-9].log -depth 1 -print -delete 2>&1
rslt = find: 1: unknown primary or operator
```

If I copy the find command displayed and execute in terminal, it works fine. So something is wrong with my rslt=$(... line.

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it print if you change it to `echo find ${logPath} -mtime +${cutOffDays} -type f -name ${dateInNameLogs}.log -depth 1 -print -delete`?

Comment: `echo` does not at all accurately represent what your command is actually running. Use `set -x` or `bash -x` instead.

Comment: Also, you can't safely store a list of filenames in a string, since every character allowed in a string is also allowed in a filename (yes, including newlines!). To handle the full range of possible filenames, you need to NUL-delimit the values and store them in an array.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, please don't encourage bad practices (in this case, unquoted expansions). And it would need to be `printf '%q ' find ${logPath} -mtime +${cutOffDays} -type f -name ${dateInNameLogs}.log -depth 1 -print -delete; printf '\n'` to distinguish bugs caused by unexpected globbing, spaces, etc; `echo` doesn't tell you the difference between `echo foo bar` and `echo "foo bar"`, and those differences are critical.

Comment: @Crashmeister, if `bash -x yourscript` doesn't make the problem obvious, please try to extend the question into a [mcve] -- code anyone can run to see the same problem, with all dependencies (ie. values for `cutOffDays` and `dateInNameLogs`) present.

Comment: ...and consider making a habit through running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here -- if you'd done so, we wouldn't have the quoting bugs.

Comment: The 'echo' was a quick display to help debug. It's not part of the actual script, but y'alls points are taken. I'll check out the two suggestions to see what they do. See answer below, I found the issue.  BTW, I tried bash -x script and it made the solution obvious. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: Charles: Point taken. I am new to bash. The bash -x was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Quote your expansions:

```
rslt=$(find "${logPath}" \
  -mtime "+${cutOffDays}" \
  -type f \
  -name "${dateInNameLogs}.log" \
  -depth 1 \
  -print \
  -delete \
  2>&1)
```

Quoting `"${dateInNameLogs}.log"` (in double quotes) tells the shell to expand the variable, but **not** to expand the result of that as a glob (or to put it through word splitting), thus ensuring that the value is evaluated by `find`, not by your shell.

This makes behavior robust *even if `nullglob`, `failglob`, or similar options are set*.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was caused by 'shopt -s nullglob'. My script does more than one thing and I had that set at the top of the file. I've moved it to specifically where is was needed and now the script runs fine.

Comment: This is part of why we ask for a [mcve] -- if you'd built code someone else could run that actually produced the same problem, that code would have included `shopt -s nullglob`, and that would have made the issue obvious.